# Why isn't `margin-top` working with this div?

Tags: html, css

Here is the example which has two `divs` and it can be seen that no matter how much I increase the value of `margin-top` for `punchline` div it isn't having any effect: https://jsfiddle.net/5frzjnbj/
It just goes only as much farther as the `logo` is from the top. Why is that? When I remove `logo` div then div starts acting "normally".

**The Code:**

```css
.logo{
  float: left;
  /*margin-left: 19px;*/
  font-size: 27;
  background-color: red; 
  margin-top:100px;
}
.punchLine{
  background-color: green;
  /*float: left;*/
  margin-top:1000px;
  clear: both;
  /*margin-left: 300px;
  font-size: 14;
  color: #264B5D;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <font color="#0072BC">Logiz</font><font color="FFFFFF">solutions.com</font>
</div> 
<div class="punchLine">
  software and tech solutions... 
</div>
```

Comment: because of  logo `float: left` remove this, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Please **DO NOT** use `<font>` tags, they are deprecated. Instead, you can use `<span>`.

Comment: Also you did not specify a `unit` for the font size value, should be `27px` for example.

Comment: @SofL If someone's solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Apply this, it help

```
.punchLine{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/Ldoyoddz/).

One needs to add `clear: both` after the `floated divs`.

Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="logo">
    <font color="#0072BC">Logiz</font><font color="FFFFFF">solutions.com</font>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="punchLine">
    software and tech solutions...
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.logo {
  float: left;
  /*margin-left: 19px;*/
  font-size: 27;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.punchLine {
  background-color: green;
  /*float: left;*/
  margin-top: 1000px;
  clear: both;
  /*margin-left: 300px;
    font-size: 14;
    color: #264B5D;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial;*/
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't `margin-top` working with this div?

Because margin properties cannot be collapsed properly when elements are floated, see the official W3 Docs on the matter: **[Box Model - Collapsin Margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)**

> Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).

---

### Solutions

**1: No Floats**

Get rid of the floating, why do you need it in the first place if the elements are going to be under each other?

```css
.logo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
}

.logo span {
  color: #0072BC;
}

.punchLine {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <span>Logiz</span>solutions.com
</div>
<div class="punchLine">
  software and tech solutions...
</div>
```

**2: Margin Bottom**

Add `margin-bottom: 100px` to the `logo div` if you want to keep the float for some reason.

```css
.logo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom:100px;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  float:left;
}

.logo span {
  color: #0072BC;
}

.punchLine {
  background-color: lightblue;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <span>Logiz</span>solutions.com
</div>
<div class="punchLine">
  software and tech solutions...
</div>
```

**3: Padding-top**

Alternatively you can add a top padding if there won't be an actual background.

```css
.logo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  float:left;
}

.logo span {
  color: #0072BC;
}

.punchLine {
  background-color: lightblue;
  clear:both;
  padding-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <span>Logiz</span>solutions.com
</div>
<div class="punchLine">
  software and tech solutions...
</div>
```

Other methods can be transparent borders or pseudo selectors but I don't think they are the best practice so I will not explain them here.

P.S Please avoid using [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) tags, they are long deprecated.